# Why is Selenium returning this error, and how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How do I fix this selenium error?

```
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location c:\Users\aaron\Downloads\webscraper\chromedriver.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Here is my code:

```
const {Builder} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

(async function openChromeTest() {
    try {
    let options = new chrome.Options().setChromeBinaryPath(`${__dirname}\\chromedriver.exe`).addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--no-sandbox", "--headless");
    let driver = await new Builder()less"
                .setChromeOptions(options)
                .forBrowser('chrome')
                .build();
    await driver.get('https://www.google.com');
    await driver.quit();
    } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    }
})();
```

I tried adding --disable-dev-shm-usage --no-sandbox --headless arguments as [WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t) says to do but that did not fix it.